# Canvas graph completely different on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

On Chrome (latest), my graph I've drawn onto a canvas looks completely different to Safari (latest) and Firefox (latest). The data plotted looks similar, but is in completely different order. The rendering is also much better on Chrome.

I can't post much of the sourcecode, but I can post snippets on request.

Screenshots:

Safari:
[image: Safari]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]
Note the 2 peaks of data have been shifted, and the "M" style of plotted data on the right of the other graphs doesn't even exist.

The points of data in Firefox and Safari are much smoother in Chrome (they don't go past the dots).

Comment: 1. Are you sure, this is not a caching problem? 2. How do you recieve the graph data? Via ajax?

Comment: @Bondye Yes I do an AJAX call for the data and don't set the cache parameter, which would be an explanation. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: could you show us the code that transforms a value into a screen Y ?

Comment: Google Chrome and Ajax are big trouble.... mostly add `async: false,` after `datatype: "json",` if it is json ;)